# How to change Title/Subtitle in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I am trying to change the title/subtitle of default "Installation location" screen as provided by install4j. But i cannot find the section in title/subtitle configuration part. The title/subtitle part is available for other screens and can be changed there.

Is there any other way or API using which i can change the Title/Subtite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titles and subtitles of standard screens are not directly configurable, but you can override the messages.

On the General Settings->Languages step, set up a custom localization file, then open the built-in editor and click on the "Override messages" tool bar button. Search for the message you want to change and click on OK. Then you can change the text in the editor.

Comment: Yes.But i want to change the subtitle. And in "Screens and Action" of default "Installation location" i dont see an option to give the subtitle. For all other screens there the option.

Comment: My answer explains how to change the messages of standard screens. For the "Installation location" screen, the message key for the subtitle is `SelectDirDesc`.